EF Core and sqlite join into results in "requires the SQL APPLY operation, not supported in sqlite"
I'm trying to use the following query but results in the error message

Translating this query requires the SQL APPLY operation, which is not supported on SQLite.

return await (from c in _dbContext.Charter
              join r in _dbContext.Roster on c.Id equals r.CharterId into rosters
              select new CharterGridData
                     {
                         CharterName = c.Name,
                         Roster = rosters.ToList()
                     }).ToListAsync();

I've tried doing things like
Roster = _dbContext.Roster.Where(r => r.CharterId == c.Id)

but it doesn't load at all (Roster table has over 2 million rows).
Is there any way to do this?

EF Core version?

Efcore 8. It works when i remove "into rosters" but the type is Roster instead of a list

Yes, this is known type of LINQ query they (EF Core team) were not willing to translate to SQL for a long time. I though they finally did it in EFC7 or 8, but according to you apparently they didn't. You probably need to use the alternative approach, but the problem would be the SQLite. I have to check.

Ideally you should consider introducing corresponding relations to your entities and just do:
public class Charter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public List<Roster> Rosters { get; set; }
}


public class Roster
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public Charter Charter { get; set; }
    public int CharterId { get; set; }
}

var charters = ctx.Charter
    .Select(c => new CharterGridData
    {
        CharterName = c.Name,
        Roster = c.Rosters.ToList()
    })
    .ToList();

Note that this will do left outer join though (can be worked around with .Where(p => p.Rosters.Any()) client/server side if needed).
Approach without fixing the entities (left outer join too):
var list = (from c in ctx.Charter
        select new CharterGridData
        {
            CharterName = c.Name,
            Roster = ctx.Roster.Where(r => c.Id == r.CharterId).ToList()
        })
    .ToList();

The inner join will require selecting intermediate object and handling data on the client side:
var list = (from c in ctx.Charter
        join r in ctx.Roster on c.Id equals r.CharterId
        select new
        {
            CharterId = c.Id,
            CharterName = c.Name,
            Roster = r
        })
    .ToList();

// todo group and select new objects


You do not need GroupJoin here. EF Core has bad support for this operator.
var query =
    from c in _dbContext.Charter
    select new CharterGridData
    {
        CharterName = c.Name,
        Roster = _dbContext.Roster.Where(r => c.Id == r.CharterId).ToList()
    };
    
var result = await query.ToListAsync();

